# Which plugin or feature support the syntax error hilight in navigator view of eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, aptana, navigator

My eclipse has a few aptana plugins. One of them support display a red x in the project icon if there are some errors in the project. But i'm not sure which plugin did this. Any one know about this? 
I know that i can also get this information in package or project explorer view, but the navigator is the one that i always used.!

Answer (score 0):

The error and warning indicators are known as Markers and are objects implementing `org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker` and declared using the `org.eclipse.core.resources.markers` extension point.

Markers can be attached to resources, the `IResource.findMarkers` methods can be used to find out what markers a resource has.

Views usually use a 'label decorator' to add the error and warning overlays to the icons (`org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ProblemsLabelDecorator` for example).